# Angular 1.5 component router browser history issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, back-button, angular-component-router

I am using angular 1.5.x with [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) and the [component router](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router).

My web app (that is not using angular) has an access to my angular app via a link.

When I arrive in my angular app, I'm stuck in it, the browser (chrome) back button is not working even if the history is "fine" -> I see by a right click on the back button that the non-angular app url is present and I can click on it, I am redirected. But the button stays stuck on the last history entry, the app...

I've seen many solutions that speaks about pushState / replaceState but I can't get it working with this component router ( as I can use ng-outlet in-page views).

**More explanation :**

- The website : http://mywebsite.com
- My angular app starts here : http://mywebsite/app
- And the link that redirects me to the angular app is :
  http://mywebsite/app/#/settings/user

The app route has a `useAsDefault` route to settings and settings has a `useAsDefault` route to user.

**I would like to not save history for some routes except for the main view changes, and find a way to return back to non-angular app.**

Could you help me to find the good way ?

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone got this issue ?

Comment: I had same issue and reason was that I had '/' in the end of `path` property string which lead to additional redirect. So make sure your `path` is 'settings/user' rather than 'settings/user/'. Mb that's the issue.